# Zero values for a percentage formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Please refer to Image 1 below, there are some products where PROD_Product.Nett_Weight and PROD_Product.Gross_Weight values are sometimes 0 so it throws up the Image 2 error.

Is there any way to by-pass this error to show "0"?

Image 1
[image]

Image 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If {PROD_Product.Gross_Weight} <> 0 Then
  {PROD_Product.Nett_Weight} / {PROD_Product.Gross_Weight} * {PROD_Product.Number_Off} * 100 
Else
  0
```